# Setting User Path Variable for Java Path

Tags: java, command-line, path, environment-variables, windows-7-x64

At my work I have user access with no admin privileges. My environment variable points to an old **JDK** at the current path: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`

From what I read on different posts such as [this](https://superuser.com/questions/867728/user-vs-system-environment-variables-do-system-variables-override-user-variabl) which states that all **user variables** override the **environment variable** except the **PATH** variable in which it concatenates the environment variable and user variable together. I have followed many different tutorials and currently have my variables set up like this in my user PATH variable.

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
JRE_HOME = C:\Users\316830207\jre7
PATH = C:\Users\316830207\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\316830207\AppData\Roaming\jdk1.7.0_79\bin
TMP = %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

If you notice my PATH variable for the user has npm path as well as jdk. The npm path was added so I could bower from the command line. That works! However the path for the JDK is never used. No matter what when I type `java -v` I get

> The system cannot find the file C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe

Since the path variable contacts the only thing I can think of is it skips my JDK path or overwrites. I have tried using command line using `setx` as I cannot use `setx /M` as I do not have admin access. I have searched for a few days now and the only conclusion is I am doing this wrong or security from my work is stopping me to overwrite JDKpath.

So my question is am I setting the JDK path incorrectly? Is there a different way I can set it? Why will it only use my environment path and not my user JDK path?

Comment: Would it not be simpler to ask the guy who is responsible for granting or over-seeing admin accesses?

Comment: No I have put in a request to access system variables and was declined. Which is annoying as I am a Java developer

Comment: Perhaps you could put in a request to have a particular JDK installed on your machine?

Comment: It takes weeks for a request to be fulfilled. It is easier if I can do it on my end.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME contains the installation path of JAVA.

Set environment variable JAVA_HOME to  installation path C:\Program Files\java\ jdk-1_7_0_08   using following steps for windows user
1. Right Click on My Computer->Properties-> Advanced->Environment Variables ->User Variables -> New 
2. Set JAVA_HOME to value C:\Program Files\java\ jdk-1_7_0_08

Comment: I set java_home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79 and path = %java_home%\bin and still java -v gives system path not user path. Think I tried this a few days ago.